# How might I customize Cycle2 pref/next functionality?

Tags: navigation, jquery-cycle2

I am interested in having Cycle2 prev/next functionality resemble that being used on the [BBC News front page top news image slideshow](http://www.bbc.com/news/).

Any tips on how to:

Make the prev/next navigation appear onhover?

Make the prev/next navigation move up from the bottom of the container?

Make the pref/next navigation pause for an interval after moving mouse from container?

Make the pref/next navigation move back down (and disappear) to the bottom of the container after interval lapses?

Transition between images using a fade when clicking prev/next buttons?

At the moment I have successfully made a Cycle2 basic container with images fading in/out but no navigation. [Here's my test sample.](http://wedesignstudios.com/test/)

Comment: All of this can be done with jQuery and CSS. check out the jquery documentation for: .hover() and .slideDown() / .slideUp().  You can also use window.setTimeout(/*function*/, /*delay in ms*/); to create a delay.  Try some of that out and report back with other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll look into them and try some things out.